# How do you match something surrounded by 'foo' and 'bar' without matching foo and bar?

Tags: regex

as opposed to regex:`'foo.+bar'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a group:

```
foo(.+?)bar
```

Then you will be able to refer to the group as `$1` or `\1`, depending on the language and what you are doing with it.

As always, let me recommend [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html) for learning all about regexes.

Comment: Not sure if not hungry notation (.*?) is available in all regex implementations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use lookaround if the regex flavor you're using (which you didn't specify) supports it. .NET, Python do, Ruby and JavaScript don't (fully), for example:

```
(?<=foo).+(?=bar)
```

matches any number of characters if they are preceded by `foo` and followed by `bar`.

Comment: perl and PHPs preg_ functions also support this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
/foo(.+)bar/
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can use:

```
foo(.+?)bar
```

or

```
foo(.*?)bar
```

The 2nd one will work even when there is nothing between foo and bar